# Use CKEditor 4 without jQuery?

Tags: ckeditor

Is it possible to use CKEditor 4 without jQuery?  I've noticed it seems to "integrate" with jQuery through an adapter, but I don't want to use jQuery on my site, so I'd prefer to use CKEditor without the adapter.  I don't see anything in the CKEditor documentation, GitHub issues, builder config files, or Stack Overflow questions about using CKEditor without jQuery, so I'm guessing it's probably not possible?  I'm mostly just surprised that the question has never been asked, so here I am asking it.  If it turns out that it is indeed possible to use CKEditor without jQuery I would be thrilled.

EDIT: I don't see jQuery in the dependencies of the `npm` package, so it shouldn't be required, but I've found no instructions on how to build it without the jQuery adapter.

Answer (score 2):

Of course, possible use CKEditor without jQuery.
jQuery adapter used only for treat CKEditor as jQuery object via $.

All basic CKEditor plugins(components) not used jQuery too.
However, a few extented CKEditor plugin as "Accessibility Checker" demand of jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

OK, after some investigation it looks like it can work without the adapter, and the adapter is not included in the build.  The issue appears to be with certain plugins requiring jQuery (the autosave plugin is the one I was having issues with).